# in a left join is it possible set limit,offset for the base table only

Tags: mysql

in a left join is it possible set limit,offset for the base table only

I'm using the sample db nwind with mysql/linux

I'm trying to limit the the rows of the 'base' TABLE (customers) IN  a left join

I  know I can rewrite the query (as a lot of others answers)
But I'm asking if there is a solution with a join
I have a class that do paging and filtering automatically.

running the query without limit,offset

```
select
customers.id,
customers.company,
customers.job_title,
orders.id,
orders.order_date
FROM customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
WHERE customers.job_title='Owner'
ORDER BY customers.id,orders.id
```

I got the expected result

```
id      company job_title       id      order_date
1       Company A       Owner   44      2006-03-24 00:00:00
1       Company A       Owner   71      2006-05-24 00:00:00
2       Company B       Owner   NULL    NULL
5       Company E       Owner   NULL    NULL
7       Company G       Owner   41      2006-03-24 00:00:00
7       Company G       Owner   68      2006-05-24 00:00:00
17      Company Q       Owner   NULL    NULL
24      Company X       Owner   NULL    NULL

#example 1
select
customers.id,
customers.company,
customers.job_title,
orders.id,
orders.order_date
FROM customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
WHERE customers.job_title='Owner'
ORDER BY customers.id,orders.id
limit 3 offset 0

d       company job_title       id      order_date
1       Company A       Owner   44      2006-03-24 00:00:00
1       Company A       Owner   71      2006-05-24 00:00:00
2       Company B       Owner   NULL    NULL

#example 2
select
customers.id,
customers.company,
customers.job_title,
orders.id,
orders.order_date
FROM customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
WHERE customers.job_title='Owner'
ORDER BY customers.id,orders.id
limit 3 offset 3
```

```
id      company job_title       id      order_date
5       Company E       Owner   NULL    NULL
7       Company G       Owner   41      2006-03-24 00:00:00
7       Company G       Owner   68      2006-05-24 00:00:00
```

for eaxample 1 I want to get

```
id      company job_title       id      order_date
1       Company A       Owner   44      2006-03-24 00:00:00
1       Company A       Owner   71      2006-05-24 00:00:00
s2       Company B       Owner   NULL    NULL
(limit 3
```

for example 2

```
id      company job_title       id      order_date
5       Company E       Owner   NULL    NULL
7       Company G       Owner   41      2006-03-24 00:00:00
7       Company G       Owner   68      2006-05-24 00:00:00
limit 3 offset 3
```

Comment: Where is the difference between what you get and what you want? I don't see any.

Comment: There's no syntax that allows you to `LIMIT, OFFSET` a joined table. You need to use subqueries for that.

Comment: I want to limit,offset the base table(customers ) but no the whole result
See CaffeinatedCod3r answer

Answer (score 0):

I think by limit base table you mean left table 
You can do it like this

```sql
select * from (

select
id,
company,
job_title
FROM customers
LIMIT 3
OFFSET 0
) as customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders 
ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
WHERE customers.job_title='owner'
ORDER BY customers.id,orders.id
```

The first bracket acts as your base table now with limited rows

Comment: Thanks you really understand the question.
I already tried  this way but always got error

Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id WHERE customers.j' at line 12

Comment: @adrian I have updated the answer.Please check it now

Comment: I just run the query it seems to get one more record from customers
This moorning   I'm involved with a release 
In the evening  (gmt+1) I will  do a complete test  and hope to accept  your answer. thx

Comment: @adrian So does this query solve your problem or is there any thing i need to change?

Comment: running your query with limit=3 offset=0t   he result of the query is ok it returns 3 records  starting from record 0 from customer
`
id      company job_title       id      employee_id     customer_id
1       Company A       Owner   44      1               1
1       Company A       Owner   71      1               1
2       Company B       Owner   NULL    NULL            NULL
`
but running the query withlimit=2 offset=3 returns

`
id      company job_title       id      employee_id     customer_id
5       Company E       Owner   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
`

Comment: running your query with limit=3 offset=0t   he result of the query is ok it returns 3 records  starting from record 0 from customer
    but running the query withlimit=2 offset=3 returns
    id      company job_title       id      employee_id     customer_id
    5       Company E       Owner   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
    while expected result is
    5       Company E       Owner   NULL    NULL
    7       Company G       Owner   41      2006-03-24 00:00:00

Comment: @adrian Limit 2 offset 3 will give you records with id (7 and 17).  
How is it giving 5 to you?